# Bootbox Confirm Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

anybody know how to fix this. I have this code to show bootbox.confirm when deleting a file, but it's not working.

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
destroy: function (e, data) {
   var that = $(this).data('fileupload');  
      if (bootbox.confirm("Delete this file(s) ?") == true ) {
        if (data.url) {
            $.ajax(data)
                .success(function () {
                      $(this).fadeOut(function () {
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                });
        } else {
           data.context.fadeOut(function () {
             $(this).remove();
           });
        }
    }
}
});
```

Comment: `bootbox.confirm` is an asynchronous method – you need to use a callback function to process its result.

Comment: Did you check the console for error messages?

Answer (score 1):

The Bootbox methods don't work like the native methods:

```
bootbox.confirm("Delete this file(s) ?", function(answer) {
    if (!answer) return; // User said "no"

    if (data.url) {
        $.ajax(data)
            .success(function () {
                  $(this).fadeOut(function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            });
    } else {
       data.context.fadeOut(function () {
         $(this).remove();
       });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use callback in order to determine user response for confirm and prompt dialogs. 
This is the signature for confirm: `bootbox.confirm(message, callback)`.

Your code should be like this

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
destroy: function (e, data) {
   var that = $(this).data('fileupload');  
      bootbox.confirm("Delete this file(s) ?", function(result) {
        if(result == true){
            if (data.url) {
                $.ajax(data)
                    .success(function () {
                          $(this).fadeOut(function () {
                            $(this).remove();
                        });
                    });
            } else {
               data.context.fadeOut(function () {
                 $(this).remove();
               });
            }
        }
    });
}
});
```

Comment: Ahh, i almost hade it, thank you so much for all of your help.

Comment: One thing though, if i check many files and click OK in the bootbox.confirm the confirm will popup for every file. Is there a way to delete multible files whit just one OK click? Thank you.

Comment: I cannot say much without entire code related to that or your design. You can use checkboxes for files then remove checked ones on confirm.

Comment: Also accept my answer (if it is enough) to inform others that your issue is solved.

Comment: Hello, Well i'm using the jQuery-File-Upload-9.7.0. And i do use checkboxes and i am confirming every file, but i just want to confirm one time for all files. Demo of the File upload script: http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ Thank you.

Comment: I cannot say much without code, can you create another question or edit that one. If you edit that, don't correct your current question. Again accept the answer, it may mislead others as the question has been solved and we are talking about another issue :)